# How to kill one of several detached screen sessions without first re-attaching to it?

Tags: gnu-screen

When inside an active screen session, one call kill all active windows in the session and exit the session with `Ctrl+a \`, however, how does one achieve the same for a session known by name (say from `screen -ls`) without first attaching to it? One idea might be to find the PID of that screen instance and kill -9 it, however, isn't there a possibility of leaving some stale session resources using this approach? Am looking for a screen specific approach for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quit` command is used to kill a session. You can give the shell command

```
screen -S sessioname -X quit
```